# evaluation of consecutive (non-nested) while loops in python

Tags: python, while-loop, control-flow

I want to evaluate two separate while loops, but I want to make sure one is done before the other is started. The code I have is in this form:

```
while condition1:
    do action1

while condition2:
    do action2
```

The loops themselves run, and they run together, but I just wanted to make sure that they are running in the order I want.

So basically, will this code continue doing action1 until condition1 is met, and only after that start doing action 2?
Or will it do action1, then action2 until one of the conditions is met and then continue doing the other action alone until the second condition is met?

Comment: Unless you use multi-threading, everything in Python is sequential.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, action1 will happen until condition1 is met and only then will loop2 even start?

Comment: Yes, that's what sequential means. Things are executed in the order that they're written.

Comment: It executes the actions until the conditions **fail** not until they're met.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the execution order will be the same with the order you write your code. In your pseudo-code, the `action1` loop won't stop until `condition1` becomes false, only after that the following `action2` loop will start.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will be executed sequentially. If you wanted it to execute both actions as long as either condition were met, you would have to write:

```
while condition1 || condition2:
    action1
    action2
```